# __block variables as out parameters of the method called from block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I used this snippet to lazily initialize some variables:

```
__block Foo *foo;

[self lazilyGetFoo:^{
    foo = <initialization here>;
}];
```

This works fine. However, now the initialization routine is moved into a method and the code below fails with EXC_BAD_ACCESS inside `loadFoo`, when assignment to `*foo` happens:

```
__block Foo *foo;

[self lazilyGetFoo:^{
    [Foo loadFoo:&foo];   /* loadFoo method: *foo = <initialization here>; */
}];
```

The reason is clear -- the address of the pointer obtained by applying `&` operator changes when being copied onto the `foo` method's stack. How to fix this?

Comment: your problem is probably a logical error, the `foo` is `nil` until you instantiate the class. therefore, you just pass a `nil` pointer as parameter, and inside the `loadFoo:` method something similar happens: `nil = <new instance>;` but that is not working.

Comment: Are you doing anything notable inside `lazilyGetFoo:` or `loadFoo:` that would offend the rule that blocks need to be moved off the stack if their original context isn't going to survive?

Comment: Something doesn't make sense. First of all, `__block` only applies to local variables. Given that, `-lazilyGetFoo:` would be pointless if it were asynchronous, as most likely it would not have completed by the time the current function is done (and then loading a local variable would be useless). If `-lazilyGetFoo:` is not asynchronous, then why would it need to "copy" anything?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a double pointer:

```
Foo *foo;
__block Foo **fooPointer = &foo;

[self lazilyGetFoo:^{
    [Foo loadFoo:foo];   /* loadFoo method: *foo = <initialization here>; */
}];
```